# How to create an X509 from CSR using Bouncy Castle to use public key for verification of a signature

Tags: java

I generate a private key with openssl, create a csr, send the csr to a server with the CA private key, sign it and generate an X509 which gets sent back to the client. The client puts the X509 into a cert store. The client signs some dummy data and tries to verify it with the public key in the cert. Verification fails. However when I generate a public key directly from the private key, verification succeeds with that public key.

Private key generation on the client

```
openssl genrsa -out ${keydir}/sign.key 2048 2>/dev/null
```

CSR

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -batch -key /tmp/sign.key -subj '/O=TableSafe/OU=secureroom/CN=sign.autoprov.tablesafe.com' -out /tmp/sign.csr
```

Send the CSR to the CA signer (see the java code below for how it handles the CSR bytes).

Then test with the following commands.

```
echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz > myfile.txt #generate some data to sign

openssl dgst -sha256 -sign sign.key -out sha256.sign myfile.txt #sign the data with the private key

openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in Sign.crt   > pubkey.pem #extract the public key from the certificate

openssl dgst -sha256 -verify pubkey.pem -signature sha256.sign myfile.txt #verify
```

Verification Failure

```
openssl rsa -in sign.key -pubout -out pubkey.pem #generate public key from private key directly

openssl dgst -sha256 -verify pubkey.pem -signature sha256.sign myfile.txt
```

Verified OK

It looks like my java code is suspect. Help appreciated.

```
public byte[] calculateX509(byte[] csrBytes) throws Exception {
    Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC();
    Date notBefore = Date.from(clock.instant());
    Duration expDuration = Duration.ofDays(3650);
    Date notAfter = Date.from(clock.instant().plus(expDuration));
    String csrStr = new String(csrBytes);
    csrStr = csrStr.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----", "");
    csrStr = csrStr.replace("-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----", "");
    csrStr = csrStr.replaceAll("\n", "");
    byte[] csrDecode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(csrStr.trim());
    PKCS10CertificationRequest decodedCsr = new PKCS10CertificationRequest(csrDecode);
    X500Name issuer = X500Name.getInstance(decodedCsr.getSubject().getEncoded());
    X509v3CertificateBuilder caBuilder = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(issuer,
            BigInteger.valueOf(clock.millis()),
            notBefore,
            notAfter,
            decodedCsr.getSubject(),
            decodedCsr.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo())
            .addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(false));

    if (Lunaks.containsAlias(strDAUTOPROVK))
    {
        char[] pw = {};
        AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("Sha256withRSA");
        AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId);
        AsymmetricKeyParameter foo = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(Lunaks.getKey(strDAUTOPROVK, pw).getEncoded());
        ContentSigner sigGen = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId).build(foo);
        JcaX509CertificateConverter providerConverter = certificateConverter.setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        X509CertificateHolder holder = caBuilder.build(sigGen);
        X509Certificate cert = providerConverter.getCertificate(holder);
        byte[] encoded = cert.getEncoded();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(writer);
        PemObject pemObject = new PemObject("CERTIFICATE", encoded);
        pemWriter.writeObject(pemObject);
        pemWriter.close();
        String strBytes = writer.toString();
        return strBytes.getBytes();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: A short Google search for "bouncy castle create x509 certificate csr" come up with a lot of results, e.g. https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=servicecatalog/oscm/oscm-master/oscm-webservices-tests/javasrc/org/oscm/ws/base/CertificateHandler.java (method generateSignedCertificate(csr)). Does that help?